# How come the Latin word "Vulgaris" acquired such negative meaning in English?

Tags: british-english, latin

Today, while reading Dan Brown's latest novel *Inferno*, I came to know that vulgar is actually derived from the Latin word *vulgaris*, literally meaning "of/pertaining to common people".

I really don't understand how come that got translated to mean `offensive to standards of decency` in English? Did the common folks exhibited indecent behavior in the Medieval times?

Comment: Vulgar: meaning "coarse, low, ill-bred" is first recorded 1640s, probably from earlier use (with reference to people) with meaning "belonging to the ordinary class" (1530).http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Vulgar&searchmode=none. Note that the same derogatory meaning is present not only in English but also in the French 'vulgaire' and the Italian 'volgare' for instance.

Comment: @Josh61 Agreed, but I'm referring to the negative usage of the word today. The novel seems to suggest that the Latin equivalent didn't convey such a negative meaning (during the Renaissance/Middle Ages) as the English word conveys now.

Comment: It's normal for terms denoting lower classes (_vulgar, common, mean_) to acquire bad meanings, while terms denoting upper classes (_noble, gentle, kind_) acquire good meanings. Everybody wants to be in the upper classes, and everybody wants to suck up to them. Enough, anyway, to adopt their values.

Comment: The common people are looked down upon by the nobility. They're unclean, they swear, they perform menial jobs, etc.

Comment: It actually originally meant 'pertaining to common people', a meaning that was probably perceived as derogatory in the following centuries. See the Etymonline link.

Comment: Most of the day-to-day activities of the common people were probably offensive to the standards of the noblemen.

Comment: @JohnLawler Really? I didn't know *gentle, kind and mean* were actually meant for the classes of people, its a TIL for me.

Comment: _Gentle_ and _kind_ actually [come from the same PIE root](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gen.pdf), as does _generous_; _mean_ comes from _medianus_ 'middle' (i.e, not Up)

Comment: Reminds me of *idiot*, which simply meant *commoner* in Ancient Greek.

Comment: Same for villain, Wikipedia states 'villanus, meaning "farmhand"... bound to the soil of a villa'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Vulgar* has a lot of shades of meaning, some depending on the user and some on the hearer. Originally, your birth decided whether you were a lady/gentleman or you were "base, common and popular" as Falstaff says in Henry V. Clearly (as is obvious to the non-working class) the labouring people cannot be expected to have the same refined sensibilities as the nobility: they prefer beer to wine, fart jokes to witty wordplay, and four-letter insults to sarcastic innuendo.  The former are  undoubtedly *vulgar*, but not necessarily inferior on that account.

Comment: **The former are undoubtedly vulgar, but not necessarily inferior on that account.** And yet, when someone calls you *vulgar* today, it no doubt conjures up an image of obscene accusations and you feel offended. For a word that only means `of common people` (which in today's democratic society, almost everyone is!)

Comment: @PrahladYeri I'd say that almost everyone has been one of the common people since the dawn of time. If the common were ever a minority - well, they wouldn't be so common, would they?

Comment: "Vulgar has a lot of shades of meaning". Like 50 shades or so?

Answer (score 1):

Specifically with regards to how 'vulgar' relates to language, a key commonality between the old meaning and the new is the notion of a standard.

Before the spread of the printed word, Latin was the lingua franca for the high-born and educated in Europe. As *the* scholarly, administrative, and clerical language across the continent, Latin was the standard language for communication deemed of any value or importance. Other languages, often regional and without much written form to speak of, were known as vulgar languages (*lingua vulgaris*), and these would be the languages of the common people. In fact, many of these languages would become the Romance languages of today, but as non-standard variants of the highest form of written Latin, were known at earlier points as [Vulgar Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulgar_Latin).

You can see in this way how the meaning of vulgar language today might relate to this notion of language that isn't fit for high, proper forms of communication. Adding the class and moral dimensions that many people have already mentioned, you can understand how the meaning became more severe and derogatory over time.

A similar transition can be seen with the words 'profane' and 'profanity.' *Profanum*, their root, originally denoted the normal, natural and mundane aspects of the world to be contrasted with *Sacrum*, the sacred aspect related to world of religion. Today, though, 'profanity' means something much more negative.